# How do you get the address of array elements given the address of the array itself in C?

Tags: c, pointers, memory-address

***edited to clarify that the array is unknown**

If the address of unknown integer array is 0x00006ffd29c78e70 (and an integer is 4 bytes), what is the address of element array[1]?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: `&A[1]`? Or what exactly is unclear?

Comment: Given `T arr[N];` `arr + i` or `&arr[i]` is the address of the ith element.

Comment: @UnholySheep, sorry should have been clearer; should have said unknown array!, will edit it.

Comment: @DeiDei clarified my question, sorry. Can't use &arr[i] because no access to array variable name.

Comment: What does *"unknown array"* mean? Unknown size? (in that case `A[1]` is potential UB). Or how do you know that there is an array allocated at that address?

Comment: `int* p = (int*)0x00006ffd29c78e70; &p[1];` This is dangerous though. What kind of scenario are you in...

Comment: @DeiDei Thank you very much! Just trying to grab a variable. I forgot about the need to add (int*).

Comment: You can use `((int*)(0x00006ffd29c78e70))` as the address of the first element of the array. `((int*)(0x00006ffd29c78e70)) + 4` is the address of the 4th element.

Comment: @DeiDei OP is must be doing some legit ass embedded programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `0x00006ffd29c78e70` is the address of a valid array of `int`s then you can assign it to a pointer:

```
int *p = (int*)0x00006ffd29c78e70;
```

then `p[1]` will give you the next element (second) in that array.

Answer (score 5):

The address of the array is also the address of its first element. This is because the array itself in memory consists solely of each of its elements (starting at index 0) in turn. Therefore if `A` is an array, `&A[0]` points to the same memory as `A`. (Note that there is a technical difference between an array of integers type and a pointer to an integer type, though they are in many cases interchangeable as the former decays into the latter under certain circumstances which are beyond the scope of this question; this is why I described them as pointing both to the same memory).

You asked about the first element, and then referred to `A[1]`. Note that `A[1]` is the second element. `A[0]` is the first element.

So in your particular example, you could do:

```
int *A = (int *)0x00006ffd29c78e70;
int *A1 = &A[1]; // points to second element
int foo = *A1; // second element contents
```

or using pointer arithmetic

```
int *A = (int *)0x00006ffd29c78e70;
int *A1 = A+1; // points to second element
int foo = *A1; // second element contents
```

Note the `+1` does not add one to the (byte) address, but increments the pointer by one `int`.

Note I have written `int` above - use the correct integer data type to represent your 4 byte integer.

Comment: Note that **the types** of "address of array" and "address of first element" **are different**.

Comment: It's the second element!

Comment: @AAAgradebeef I know - see above. At some stage I am pretty sure the question asked about the first element. But I have clarified.

Comment: @GradyPlayer increments it in byte terms by one `sizeof(int)` (not `sizeof(*int)`, but that's the same as incrementing the pointer in `int` terms by one `int`, i.e. it points to the next `int`.

Comment: @pmg clarified.

Answer (score 0):

Elements are at

```
unsigned char *addressofarray = whatever;
unsigned char *secondelement = addressofarray + sizeof arrayelement;
unsigned char *nthelement = addressofarray + n * sizeof arrayelement;
```

Comment: The contents are integers, not `unsigned char *` (allegedly - he says 4 bytes)

Answer (score 0):

you just got a pointer to acess any thing in array as:

```
  int *ptr = (int*) 0x00006ffd29c78e70;
```

you can acess any element as:

```
 *(ptr+i) //i is the index
```